# Record and Playback Tool For Desktop Application

Tags: desktop-application

I have a short deadline to test a desktop application. Which record and playback software can be used for desktop application (developed on .NET)?

Comment: Ranonex , Test complete

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends what kind of app is this. WPF, UWP, WinForms or Win32? All of them might be developed in .NET.

There is a lot of tools (mostly paid). I would suggest [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/), as this is the easiest (but not the cheapest one). Then there is Coded UI, for which you need Visual Studio Enterprise Edition (which cost more than a lot).

You can use also some other tools such as Autoit, [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/) or [pyWinAuto](http://pywinauto.github.io/)

At last there is a free and my favourite tool, but you need to write some of the automation code by yourself (i've seen also recording tools there, but they can't do everything). It's done my Microsoft and it's called [WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver) and should be combined with [Appium](http://appium.io/)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of short deadline I recommend you use [Ranorex](https://www.ranorex.com/). It has:

- 30-days trial period
- good Record and Playback feature
- Visual Studio like interface

Check this guide to [create test in 20 minutes](https://www.ranorex.com/help/latest/ranorex-studio-fundamentals/ranorize-20-minutes/1-download-install-ranorex-studio/)

Answer (score -1):

Coded UI is the best I guess.And AutoIT can do the same.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27589)

Comment: How could this not be an answer ?Because he is asking for a tool.So codedui is a tool.Please explain me why @nitin say so.

Comment: It looks commentary rather then an details answer. please refer the above answer's & guideline... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Nitin, Not all the quaschens have detailed answers. Some have shorter answers like above.Use common sense.

Comment: Means you accept it's a comment & we have example of good answer above.