# What is the best tool to record web actions and export scripts?

Tags: action-recording, export, web-testing

I need a tool that records user action on browser and generates scripts 9preferaably in multiple formats) for me to run afterwards. What will be the best tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Record and Playback Tool For Desktop Application](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/37473/record-and-playback-tool-for-desktop-application)

Comment: I want the tool to work on web applications.

Comment: https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/ is a good one. I have used it and liked it.

Answer (score 2):

I sadly have to break with the rest and recommend ranorex for actual record and playback. Selenium is fickle and needs a solid framework around it to produce solid tests. The selenium IDE can't provide that because it doesn't know the needs of your application.

Of course ranorex doesn't either but it's much more robust out of the box (which in my opinion doesn't make up for it's many other short comings though) and creates reasonable results.

At the end of the day I have to say though that any record and playback tool will only suffice for the most simple of cases and does rarely provide all the tools needed to build truly performant and reliable test.

Comment: Thanks for the last paragraph. Recording is not a Silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

To test web applications and record it you can use the most used Selenium IDE. It is very easy to learn and documentation is also very precise. You just need to download the extension and than it's all set.

You can start a new project by providing base URL. Afterwards you can multiple test under that project. The Selenium IDE records user's actions and than integrate the actions in the form of script. You can play, pause, stop the recorded script anytime.

It also gives you the simplified form of actions in the form of Command,Target,Value and Description so that you can modify the test accordingly. Also you can save the project and tests.

It also gives Log in which you can track the working of the script. It's very easy for recording test and learning automation. You can do a lot more with it. Here's the official documentation of the [Selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp)

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE is best record and playback tool for web applications. The new Selenium IDE has many useful feature that makes the tool unique from all the other tools. Here is the [blog](https://www.qatouch.com/blog/spectacular-arrival-of-revamped-selenium-ide/) which explains about the new features and it benefits. Kindly go through it.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium IDE for web (open source) and testcomplete for commercial(paid version)
Appium desktop for mobiles. You can tap and verify whether its working. 
Inspector for desktop
Provided you are working on Selenium/Appium

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple tools available for recording web actions and generating scripts, but some of the most popular ones are:

1. Selenium IDE - This is a plugin for the Firefox browser that can be used to record user actions and generate scripts in multiple formats, including Java, Python, Ruby, and C#.
2. Katalon Studio - This is a free, powerful, and versatile test automation tool that can be used to record web actions and generate scripts in multiple formats, including Java, Python, and Groovy.
3. UiPath - This is a powerful and flexible RPA tool that can be used to record web actions and generate scripts in multiple formats, including Python and .NET.
4. HP UFT/QTP - This is a commercial test automation tool that can be used to record web actions and generate scripts in multiple formats, including VBScript.

Ultimately, the best tool for you will depend on your specific needs and requirements, so you may need to try out several tools before finding the one that works best for you.